# Jquery ajax load HTML to whole document

Tags: jquery

I just want to load the response html from jquery ajax call to my whole document, but page is empty. How to fix it?

Snippet of my jquery function:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: url,
}).done(function(data){
    console.log("data: " + data);
    $(document).html(data);
}).error(function(xhr, status, error){
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    console.log("error: " + err.Message);
});
```

In data is the complete HTML which i want to show.

Comment: $('body').html(data);

Comment: what is the out of `console.log("data: " + data);`?

Comment: why don't your do a simple redirect? `window.location=url`

Comment: A redirect won't work because my spring modelattribut will be erased. @Matei Mihai the 'body' reference seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
$('body').html(data);
```

it will work like expected. Thanks to the commenter.